# Deploy ans run the war file on aws apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, war

I have my war installed on the path `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/xyz` where xyx is my war file name. The apache tomcat is running on an AWS instance. How can i run my application from there . When i run it using `http://ipaddressofmyawsserver/xyz` it says not found but when i do  `http://ipaddressofmyawsserver:8080` it shows HELLO WORLD!! Can some tel me what is the mistake I am doing in running my application.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

`http://publicip:8080/xyz` ?

Ideally the above line should work

And make sure that you are providing your public ip and not the internal ip of your machine.

Comment: Why do I have to use the port number 8080? Can I not do it without using the port number?and just the IP or the URL?